# Unable to access the Microsoft graph endpoint with angular-oidc token

Tags: angular, scope, microsoft-graph-api, postman, angular-oauth2-oidc

Am pretty new to angular-oauth2-oidc, Unable to access the Microsoft Graph API, using the graph token that we get as the id_token in angular-oauth2-oidc.

the AuthConfig

```
    export const authCodeFlowConfig: AuthConfig = {

  // Url of the Identity Provider
  issuer: '<sample_issuer>',
  

  // URL of the SPA to redirect the user to after login
  redirectUri: window.location.origin+"/",
  responseType: 'id_token',
  clientId: 'client_id', //ApplicationID
  strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation:false,
  oidc: true,
  scope: 'openid, profile, email, api, User.Read',
  showDebugInformation: true,
  timeoutFactor: 0.01,
}
```

Here my assumption would be once the authentication is successful then that graph token would have enough permission to access the

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value

But when I am trying to hit the endpoint with the token that I get from the oidc authentication using the postman am getting the following error

[image]

While decoding the token using jwt.io, I can find that the token doesn't have profile or any other scopes enabled.

I tried using the sample application from angular-oauth2-oidc
https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/tree/master/projects/quickstart-demo

Below is the code sample to trigger the login

[image]

Any help or guidance will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check here.

1. You are using OIDC. Please ensure you are using **access token** and not **id token** to access Graph API.

   Use something like this to obtain token:

   ```
    GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client id}&response_type=id_token%20token&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/&response_mode=fragment&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read&state=12345&nonce=678910
   ```

   Please note, the response contains both id token and access token(bearer)here. Only extract out bearer token to call Graph API. Make sure you are checking scopes against access  token.
2. Also, I would suggest try and run in POSTMAN first to isolate your issue from code.